# Masking a multitask output where values are missing

Tags: keras, deep-learning

The problem is to create a network for a multi-task problem where not all targets are provided, e.g. we have a 256 long binary input vector and 8 outputs whereas not all the 8 numbers are provided. Moreover, the known targets vary so one sample might have all the 8 targets known, whereas the other one only targets 2nd, 3rd, 5th and 7th. How can I properly mask the output from my network such that the propagated error flows only through the known outputs and is calculated on them?

I came up with something like this:
It computes the accuracy and error based on the known outputs (source: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3893)
Toy problem:

```
#toy problem
MASK_VALUE = -1
n = 25 # # datapoints
n_tasks = 8 # tasks / # binary classes
input_dim = 256 # vector size

# generate random X vectors and random 
# Y labels (binary labels [0,1] or -1 for missing value
x_tr = np.random.rand(n, input_dim)
x_test = np.random.rand(5, input_dim)
y_tr = np.random.randint(3, size=(n, n_tasks))-1

MASK_VALUE = -1
def build_masked_loss(loss_function, mask_value=MASK_VALUE):
    """Builds a loss function that masks based on targets

    Args:
        loss_function: The loss function to mask
        mask_value: The value to mask in the targets

    Returns:
        function: a loss function that acts like loss_function with masked inputs
    """

    def masked_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
        mask = K.cast(K.not_equal(y_true, mask_value), K.floatx())
        return loss_function(y_true * mask, y_pred * mask)

    return masked_loss_function

def masked_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    dtype = K.floatx()
    total = K.sum(K.cast(K.not_equal(y_true, MASK_VALUE), dtype))
    correct = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), dtype))
    return correct / total
```

Then I created the following model:

```
input_values = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(input_values)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
network_outputs = Dense(num_of_targets, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=input_values, outputs=network_outputs) 
model.compile(loss=build_masked_loss(K.binary_crossentropy), optimizer='adam', metrics=[masked_accuracy])
```

The problem is that it does not predict multiple values but only 1 every single time. I found a solution in here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3206 but it's obsolete already; the code was modified using masking and multiplying:

```
mask_input = Input(shape=(n_tasks,))
mask = Masking(mask_value=-1)(mask_input)
network_outputs = Multiply()([network_outputs, mask])
model = Model(inputs=[input_values, mask_input], outputs=network_outputs)
```

yet it returns

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-260-2344b9c44c60> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x=[x_tr, y_tr], y=y_tr)
[..]
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [25,8] vs. [25]
     [[{{node loss_21/multiply_30_loss/mul_2}}]]
```

I tried to find a similar problem but there was no results.

UPDATE
I changed a code a bit to

```
input_values = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
mask_input = Input(shape=(1, n_tasks))
mask = Masking(mask_value=-1, input_shape=(None, n_tasks))(mask_input)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(input_values)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
network_outputs = Dense(n_tasks, activation='sigmoid')(x)
network_outputs = Multiply()([network_outputs, mask])
model = Model(inputs=[input_values, mask_input], outputs=network_outputs)
model.compile(loss=build_masked_loss(K.binary_crossentropy), optimizer='adam', metrics=[masked_accuracy])#(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss=K.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and resize the output vector before passing it to the network
`y_t = y_t.reshape(n, 1, n_tasks)`. It started training but the predicted output is only 1's.

```
model.fit(x=[x_tr, y_tr], y=y_tr, epochs=10)
[...]
Epoch 10/10
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 495us/step - loss: 5.1481e-04 - masked_accuracy: 1.5267
```

test:

```
full_mask = np.array([1] * n_tasks)
model.predict([x_tr[0].reshape(1, -1), full_mask.reshape(1, 1, n_tasks)])
array([[[0.9953357 , 0.9996921 , 0.99997514, 0.99980736, 0.999151  ,
         0.9999542 , 0.9999195 , 0.99996036]]], dtype=float32)
```